# Restriction of Lie brackets of extensions of vector fields tangent to a submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

If $\pi:M\rightarrow I$ is a surjective submersion and $S$ is a fiber, we know that $S$ is an embedded submanifold of $M$. If $X,W$ are two vector fields on $S$ we can extend them to $M$, $\tilde{X},\tilde{M}$. I want to prove that $[\tilde{X},\tilde{W}]|_S=[X,W]$.

We know, If I say well, that $\iota^*(\Omega^0(S))$ is isomorphic to $\Omega^0(S)$, where $\iota$ is the inclusion, so if $f$ is a smooth function on $S$, $[\tilde{X},\tilde{W}]|_S(f)=[\tilde{X},\tilde{W}]|_S(g\circ\iota)=(\tilde{X}\circ\tilde{W})|_S(g\circ\iota)-(\tilde{W}\circ\tilde{X})|_S(g\circ\iota)=(\tilde{X}\circ\tilde{W})(g)\circ\iota-(\tilde{W}\circ\tilde{X})(g)\circ\iota=[X,W](g\circ\iota)$

make sense?

thanks for all help me.

Comment: This is a good start but you have to justify that $XY(f\circ i)= (XY(f)) \circ i$. My suggestion is to write everything in local coordinates where $S$ is a coordinate subspace in $R^n$ and then compute the Lie bracket of the extension.

Comment: Oh, right. With $(XY(f))\circ i$ on the right you mean $(\tilde{X}\circ\tilde{Y}(f))\circ i$? And you agree with me that any function on $S$ is the pullback of a function of $M$?

Comment: Yes on both items.

Comment: If I write $X=X^1\partial_1+ X^2\partial_2$ for semplicity and $W=W^1\partial_1$ then an extension of $X$ and $W$ can be write using partition of unity and using charts. I try it.